# In Laravel, how can I make all fields available to the user when they edit a form (even empty fields)?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a standard form created using Laravel and the Vue JS framework. A part of my form looks like this:

I've created an edit page and my edit.blade.php looks like:

```
<div>
    <project-form-for-desserts
        :all-desserts="{{ $allDesserts }}"
        :all-dessert-values="{{ $allDessertValues }}"
        :project="{{ $theProject }}"
        :project-property-values="{{ $theProject->dessertValues }}"
        :project-photos="{{ $theProject->photos }}"
    />
</div>
```

For reference the create.blade.php looks like this (where the entry fields represent an empty array):

```
<div>
    <project-form-for-desserts
        :all-desserts="{{ $allDesserts }}"
        :all-dessert-values="{{ $allDessertValues }}"
        :project="{{ $newnewProject }}"
        :project-property-values="[]"
        :project-photos="[]"
    />
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function edit(Project $project)
{
    return view('projects.edit',
        [
            'allDesserts' => Desserts::all(),
            'allDessertDefaults' => DessertDefaults::all(),
            'theProject' => $project
        ]);
}
```

**However, when I go to the edit page for a specific project then it only shows the fields that were filled in initially. It doesn't show the empty fields. How can I fix this so it shows both the filled entry fields and the unfilled entry fields?**

The form looks like:

```
<template>
    <v-card>
            <v-form>
                <v-card>
                    <v-row>
                        <v-col>
                            <v-card-title>Name</v-card-title>
                            <v-text-field
                                v-model="theProject.name"
                                label="Please enter the dessert name" 
                            />
                        </v-col>
                        <v-col>
                            <v-card-title>Reference</v-card-title>
                            <v-text-field
                                v-model="theProject.type"
                                label="Please enter the dessert type" 
                            />
                        </v-col>
                    </v-row>
                </v-card>
                <v-card 
                    v-for="selectDessertProperty in theProjectProperties"
                    :key="selectDessertProperty"
                    flat
                >
                    <v-row>
                        <v-col>
                            <v-card-title>Name</v-card-title>
                            <v-select
                                v-model="theProject.property_values[selectDessertProperty]"
                            />
                        </v-col>
                    </v-row>
                </v-card>
                <v-btn @click="addDessert"> Add </v-btn>
            </v-form>
    </v-card>
</template>
```

Comment: Something is going wrong with the rendering of the form fields. Please show the code which controls the form and form fields themselves.

Comment: I've added a section of the form above. Oddly, the top two entries where v-model = theProject.something always shows on the page even if they're empty however the following fields don't

Comment: It is notable that the other fields are all rendered in a loop. What are the contents of the variable you are looping over, theProjectProperties? What happens if you replace the entire loop with {{ theProjectProperties }}? Do you see an array or object of properties as you expect? If so, replace the v-select with {{ theProject.property_values[selectDessertProperty] }} so you can see exactly what you are passing into v-select. Does it look how you expect, and match what v-select is expecting?

Comment: {{ theProjectProperties }} shows an array and inside it are objects. So if I have 200 desserts then inside  {{ theProjectProperties }} is [{"id":1, "dessertName":"egg custard", "dessertType":"creamy"}{"id":2 etc......same as before with different values...}.....]

Comment: That this doesn't show anything is likely a key. Perhaps some data is not loaded correctly, or some variable names or values are not aligned as expected? If you continue to dump the data on screen to explore it, or use vue devtools if you prefer, you should be able to continue to explore what you have and see if it matches what you expect. Is {{ selectDessertProperty }} correct? Is it's value a key in {{ theProject.property_values }} is {{ theProject.property_values }} an array or object as expected with the keys you expect?